# Returning reason for node-fetch query results not matching rather than giving undefined. nodejs node-fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

Note the API key has had the last characters removed as I was told not to post api keys linked to my personal account.

I am working on getting weather results from openweathermap.org Everything seems to be working except if I input an invalid city name or area code it returns undefined. I would like to return a reason for the failure in the console.
below are the dependencies being used:

```
  "name": "node-final-exercise",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

heres the code snippet I'm working on right now.

```
   // Goals for project
// API's    OpenWeatherMap api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=8d0f96c686dbab4b20d5dda13
// API's zip code specific api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip={zip code},{country code}&appid={API key}
// a. use node app.js (areacode) to connect to weather api should also accept ( city ) and (state) like cleveland ohio
// b. parse data from weather api
// c. ouput JSON parsed data into a readable format in the console.

const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const city = process.argv.slice(2);
(async () => {
  try {
    await fetch(
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=8d0f96c686dbab4b20d5dda13`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((body) => console.log(body.main))
      .catch(error =>{console.error("first catch error : ", error)})     
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("error : ",error.message);
  }
})();
```

[console results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieQja.png)

Comment: you want an error to be displayed ?

Comment: Hi @JimClayton thanks for responding, yeah so what I would like to do is at least when a non matching query is input it should say " No matching location" for example instead of just returning "undefined". I am not sure though whether the catch error would pick that up as an error or if it falls under something else. This is my first attempt using node and the fetch-api so I am blundering through this a little.